# c# to AS400 / JD Edwards - run program - Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, database-connection, ado, ibm-midrange, jdedwards

UPDATE: The code example below works.  I changed the connection string.  That was the problem.  For an alternative (non-ADO) solution, see Mike Wills's link in the comments.

I have a c# class that (if I ever get it working) runs a program written in RPG code on AS/400 - JD Edwards.  I know next to nothing about AS/400 and/or JD Edwards.

I've got other classes in my (intranet) web app that connect to JD Edwards, running SQL queries and setting/getting data.  All of these are using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries dll and are working great.

For this, I wrote a similar class using the aforementioned dll, but it wasn't working.  I even read somewhere online that you can't run a program using this dll.  I found that a little fishy, but on suggestion from my JD Edwards co-worker, I scrapped the class and re-wrote it using the adodb dll.  No data need be returned from this program run.  I just want the program to run.

Here is a dummified version of the class:

```
    private void runJDEProgram() {
        ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection();

        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=ABABAB;Data Source=111.111.111";



        ADODB.Command cmdDetail = new ADODB.Command();
        cn.Open(); //has to be open before setting an active connection.
        cmdDetail.ActiveConnection=cn;


        cmdDetail.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText;

        cmdDetail.CommandText = "{{CALL BLAH.BLAH(?,?)}}";


        cmdDetail.Prepared = true;

        cmdDetail.Parameters.Append(cmdDetail.CreateParameter("P1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10, "BLAH123"));
        cmdDetail.Parameters.Append(cmdDetail.CreateParameter("P2", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10, "BLAH456"));

        object dummy = Type.Missing; //otherwise, we couldn't get past this.

        cmdDetail.Execute(out dummy, ref dummy, 0);

        cn.Close();
    }
```

Here's the error I get when it runs:

```
{"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}
```

Where am I screwing up?  Thanks!

EDIT: The connection string works when querying the AS/400 to get/set data.  Does it need to be modified for an operation like this, or for use with ADO?

Comment: What version of Client Access are you using?

Comment: How do I find that out?  Is that something on the JD Edwards side?

Comment: That would be something installed on your computer. I don't know JDE. But as I think about it more, you may not NEED Client Access installed. But it is MUCH easier to work with the data.

Comment: Is that a program or a dll or...what?  Sorry.  Would such a thing need to exist on the webserver as well?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, I found this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzahgicca2.htm

It looks interesting, but I don't think it's going to do much for me on this problem.  Thanks, though, for suggesting it.

Comment: The later versions 5.4, 6.1, and 7.1 have a .NET ADO driver. That is what I use for all connections. I have a [Github project](https://github.com/MikeWills/IBM-i-.NET-Interface) that wrote to make working with IBM i data easier. Though the code is a bit out of date, it works well with this driver.

Comment: Apparently we're already using that.  An excel spreadsheet is able to use vaguely similar code to run a JDE program (of course, the code's in vb).  The above class is my attempt at a translation.

Comment: Take a look at what I am doing in [my interface](https://github.com/MikeWills/IBM-i-.NET-Interface/blob/master/IbmI.Net/IbmISql.cs). I don't use the ADO method. See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help @MikeWills - the problem was the connection string.  The example above now works.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string has to be different for this, for some reason.  I don't use the same connection string for the other classes that just run queries.  The above connection string worked fine (with the appropriate values, of course).

It will prompt for password, but the JDE folks here wanted that.